# Программа которая обновляет сама себя

Tags: c#, ооп

есть задача, написать программу на c#, исполняемый файл test.exe
и есть новая версия программы которая лежит в папке new/test.exe
вот написанный код:
firstmethod запускается при открытии программы, secodmethd при нажатии на кнопку обновить

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace test
{
    class Class1
    {
        public Version version; //= typeof(Form1).Assembly.GetName().Version;
        public string s1 = "empty", s2 = "empty";
        public void FirstMethod()
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"..\test.exe")) { s1 = "yes"; }
            if (File.Exists(@"..\newtest.exe")) { s2 = "yes"; }

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

            if (File.Exists(@"..\test.exe") && (File.Exists(@"..\newtest.exe")))
            {
                File.Delete(@"..\test.exe");
                File.Move(@"..\newtest.exe", @"..\test.exe");

                Process.Start(@"..\test.exe");
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        public void SecondMethod()
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"new\test.exe"))
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"newtest.exe"))
                {
                    File.Delete(@"newtest.exe");
                }
                File.Copy(@"new\test.exe", "newtest.exe");
            }

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            //Process.Start(@"new\test.exe");

            Process cmd = new Process();//создаем новый объект класса
            cmd.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", @"C:\Users\UserPC\source\repos\test\test\bin\Debug\new\test.exe");
            cmd.Start();

            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

я придумал при нажатии на кнопку обновить, создавать рядом с test.exe копию обновления под именем newtest.exe, затем открыть new/test.exe и из него удалить test.exe и переименовать newtest.exe, но файл new/test.exe не удаляет и не переименовывает файл. с чем может быть связано?

Comment: Если файл используется, то вы не можете его переместить или удалить. Windows позволяет (и то не всегда) только переименовать запущенный файл. Вы можете попробовать сделать такой алгоритм: Переименовываем запущенный файл (test_old.exe например) - Закидываем в эту директорию новую версию (test.exe) - Запускаем новую версию и закрываем старую. Но повторюсь, это работает не у всех, по этому лучше сделать некого посредника, который будет ждать завершения процесса основной программы и после заменит файл на новую версию. Я лично делал CMD, который создавался в корне приложения и уже он все менял.

Comment: Я для себя и сделал просто программу - обновлятор. Текущая программа запускает обновлятор и закрывается. Обновлятор уже скачивает новую версию, удаляет старую, делает что надо в общем и в конце запускает новую версию. Весь процесс автоматизирован, юзер просто жмет кнопку "обновить" и наслаждается процессом.

Comment: А почему не использовать средства типа ClickOnce?

Comment: поставили задачу использовать только 2 exe файла, именно test.exe и new/test.exe, поэтому нельзя использовать сторонний обновлятор

Comment: можете показать или что-то похожее как вы делали с CMD, пытаюсь сделать но пока не получается. Либо подсказать почему у меня открытый new/text.exe не может удалить уже закрытые test.exe и скопированный newtest.exe, может они как-то связаны или я использую Process.Start не в том месте

Comment: @ГеннадийП Наверно потому, что он не всегда актуален? Например почти все приложения, что я разрабатываю - портативны, они должны запускаться с любого места (хоть с флешки) без установки. Сделаете такое с ClickOnce? Также лично я против данной технологии по одной маааленькой причине - у меня SSD на 60гб всего, 30 из которых - система и студия, мне не очень нравиться, когда мой диск забивают всяким мусором (а это делает ClickOnce, ставя все в на диск C).

Comment: @unnamed082 Если у вас некое учебное задание, то сделайте как я написал выше - просто переименуйте файл, этого будет достаточно. Если брать CMD в плане посредника, то вам нужно написать скрипт, который будет находится в ресурсах программы и тогда последовательность следующая: Распаковываем скрипт и запускаем - Закрываем приложение - Скрипт ждет завершения процесса и как только он завершится, меняет файлы - В конце скрипт запускает новую версию. - При запуске программа ищет этот файл и удаляет его если надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, через переименование самого себя и перемещение себя всё получилось)